# how to detect available language versions (Locale) of a website programmatically?

Tags: javascript, localization, http-headers, locale

I want to know in how many languages (user language) a website is available through any programmatic way.

Answer (score 0):

The way I do it in my browser is to REQUEST the language code I prefer, in this way...

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function(details){

  for(var i=0; i<details.requestHeaders.length; i++){

   if(details.requestHeaders[i].name=='Accept-Language'){details.requestHeaders[i].value=Options[285]+','+details.requestHeaders[i].value; break;}

  } return {requestHeaders:details.requestHeaders};

 },{urls:['<all_urls>']},['blocking','requestHeaders']);}
```

But there's no guarantee of it working unless the language is available and the server is paying attention to this header.

NB: Options[285] being a variable that contains a valid language code.